# Generate java classes from a xsd file with leve package

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I want to know if is possible to generate Java classes with leve package by a xsd file.

I know jaxb parser but it didn´t generate to me level package, all files are in the same package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any way to have JAXB generate artifacts in a package structure that follows the nesting of your elements defined in a schema, which isn't to say that it's not possible. However, I will say that a best practice is to keep an eye on your package dependencies in Java--specifically, you want to follow what is known as the [Acycic Dependencies Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acyclic_dependencies_principle) with your package design.

Mike Clark's [JDepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html) can be a big help to you in understanding what your packages depend on and it's pretty easy to insert its report generation into your build process. A natural advantage of JAXB generating all artifacts into one package is that there are no worries about creating an unwanted package dependency cycle. In general, I would suggest you strive to keep things as simple as possible and leaving the JAXB-generated artifacts in one package strikes me as nicely simple.